Ollama with llama3.2:3b and GPU memory usage
I am currently running Ollama via docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/ollama/ollama
The only model I currently am running is reported via /api/ps llama3.2:3b-instruct-q8_0 as:
https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/api.md#list-running-models
{"models":[{"name":"llama3.2:3b-instruct-q8_0","model":"llama3.2:3b-instruct-q8_0","size":20735514624,"digest":"e410b836fe6132b8c5e09bd83156dab0ce2c19f371e0bce2d77e993f8a65241a","details":{"parent_model":"","format":"gguf","family":"llama","families":["llama"],"parameter_size":"3.2B","quantization_level":"Q8_0"},"expires_at":"2024-12-01T00:50:21.002936228Z","size_vram":20735514624}]}

The part I am confused on however is according to Nvidia-smi, I'm using 20 gb of VRAM?

I would have expected this model to use a lot lower. Is Ollama loading multiple instances of the same model?
